# Attach to a gdb process running in a different session?

Tags: unix, gdb

When running gdb in tty1 can you attach to it from tty2 without using gdbserver? Or is gdbserver necessary (e.g. `gdbserver 127.0.0.1:8000 ./program` in tty1 and `gdb target 127.0.0.1:8000` in tty2)? Because, both the debugger and the debuggee are on the same machine (but in different tty/sessions) gdbserver seems like an overkill?

I'm new to gdb, so there may be some piece of functionality that I'm missing? I've tried just starting `gdb ./program` in tty1 and then `gdb attach <PID of that gdb program in tty1>` hoping that gdb will find some more "direct" way to connect, but it yielded an error `ptrace: Operation not permitted.`. Naturally, running gdb as root isn't ideal neither.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that it's needed to attach an IDE, not just another terminal (I'm too weak to use gdb CLI).

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`?  If it's not `0` then you likely don't have the right permissions/capabilities to PTRACE a process that isn't a descendent.  You can read `man ptrace` and search for the above file to find out more.